# Pivot columns is hidden on model Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have Post model with relation:

```
public function prices() {
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Price', 'postable');
}
```

I have a separate table postables with columns:

```
- postable_id
- postable_type
- custom (type: json)
```

Why when I want do: `$post->pivot->custom` I get null, why? When I do `dd($post)` column `custom` not found in collection.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the custom attributes when you define the relation, like this:

```
public function prices() {
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Price', 'postable')->withPivot('custom');
}
```

If you want to cast the custom attribute, you would have to create a model for the pivot table, like this:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class Postable extends Pivot
{
    protected $casts = [
        'custom' => 'array',
    ];
}
```

Reference this model in your relation definition:

```
return $this->morphedByMany('App\Price', 'postable')
    ->using('App\Postable')
    ->withPivot('custom');
```

Now you can retrieve the value like this:

```
foreach ($post->prices as $price) {
    echo $price->pivot->custom;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But you don't know, how I can write column `custom` in casts? Can I do this in my Post model or not?

Comment: You have to create a model for the pivot table: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models

Comment: Thanks very much :)

Comment: Sorry. But why we can't write withPivot in pivotModel? Example: `protected $withPivot = ['custom']` this is not working.

Comment: You have to specify it in the relation. See the updated answer for an elaborated example.

Comment: But why we can't add pivot column globally? I need in every relation write: `withPivot('custom')`

Comment: Only in your model definitions, so just two times.